# Geographic indicator API for india

Tags: database, api, statistics, geography

Hi i recently came across  a site http://www.azavea.com/Products/Kaleidocade/Home.aspx,  Is there a similar geographic indicator website dedicated to India alone, covering all states? I want to know the details like fuel prices,vegetable prices etc., I found indiastat.com but it is very expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to log on to [www.mapmyindia.com/api](http://www.mapmyindia.com/api) to get further clarification as to what api's you are looking for specifically.